# How to create an array entry for each line of a text file using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, text

I am having difficulty creating an array entry out of each line of a text file in node.js

My array is called "temp." I am able to console.log each line in the following code:

```
var temp = [];
const readline = require('readline');
const fs = require('fs');
let rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream('./lib/Sphinx.txt')
});
let line_no = 0;
rl.on('line', function(line) {
    line_no++;
    console.log(line); //this successfully prints out every line
    temp.push(line); //this would ideally create a new array entry for each line

});
```

However, when I run this code:

```
console.log(temp.length)
//returns 0
console.log(temp.size)
//returns undefined
```

Asynchronous function calls are causing this to happen. As a result, I am unable to access the array values outside of the function itself, which is the only objective.

Help is appreciated.
Thanks,
Nakul

Answer (score 1):

```
rl.on('line', function (line) {
    line_no++;
    console.log(line); //this successfully prints out every line
    temp.push(line); //this would ideally create a new array entry for each line
}).on('close', function (line) {
    // EOF
    console.log(temp);
    console.log(temp.length);
});;
```

- Write `console.log(temp.length)` instead of `console.log(temp.size)` that should work
- You should get complete array at the end of your line by line read, i.e. on `close` event.

Comment: I'm getting 0 for that.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It turns out that my original code was actually correct. It was just a matter of asynchronous execution.